# Add SubQuery in existing subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Table Structures:
**tblCustomer**

```
Customer_id  created   field1      field2        cardno
--------------------------------------------------------    
1014     Test1     Cell Phone  123146        1234567890
1015     Test2     Email       abc@xyz.com   2345678891
```

**tbl_TransactionDishout**

```
Trnx_id   offerNo   TerminalID      Created                  cardno
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1014      170924690436418 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547  1234567890
```

Is it possible to get the result as below date-wise records:

```
               Enrolled   Enrolled as Email  Enrolled as Text Deals Redeemed   
<First Date>   7          5                  2                6
<Next Date>    9          3                  6               14
```

My current query is something like this:

```
select created,
count(field1) Enrolled,
count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell
from tblCustomer c
group by created 
order by created desc
```

But It's giving me the result of the date contained only in tblCustomer table..

Now, How to get Deals_redeemed..?
relation between tbl_transaction and tblCustomer is having same cardno...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding table tbl_TransactionDishout is an offer, and if it is followed through a record will be inserted into tblCustomers; if not, nothing will change. So deals redeemed is count of non-existing records in tblCustomers for given cardno:

```
select t.created,
   count(c.field1) Enrolled,
   count(case c.field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
   count(case c.field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
   count(case when c.field1 is null then 1 end) [Deals Redeemed]
from tbl_TransactionDishout t left join tblCustomer c 
   on t.cardno = c.cardno
group by t.created
order by t.created desc
```

EDIT: c.created changed to t.created

Comment: Column 'tblCustomer.created' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.